# Woocommerce - disable add_to_cart button when product is on backorder

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to disable button "Add to cart" when product is available on backorder.

I tried something like this, but doesn't work at all:

```
function remove_add_to_cart ($product){ 
if($product->is_on_backorder){
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');}}
```

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution (depending on what you actually want to do) could be to remove the add_to_cart form entirely if the product is on backorder.  There could be other solutions as well, but your question is a little vague.  This is specifically for the product single page.  You didn't specify in the question.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'check_if_backordered', 1 );
function check_if_backordered(){
    global $product;
    if ($product->is_on_backorder()){
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
        // Here you can insert whatever you want in its place
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, but also i meant for single product page, so you send me correct information. Everything works now, thank u a lot! with this code: 

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'check_if_backordered', 1 );
function check_if_backordered(){
    global $product;
    if ($product->is_on_backorder()){
         add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
     
    }
}